# How to launch Arduino after successful installation on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, installation, arduino

I've installed Arduino 1.8.9 for Linux 64 bits directly from arduino.cc website, on my Ubuntu 18.04LTS

After a successful installation I get the Arduino folder inside ~/Documents

However I don't know how to launch the Arduino application itself. There are many files like "arduino", "arduino-builder", arduino-linux-setup.sh" that open as text in the Terminal application.

So I'm stuck here.
Thanks for reading me.

Answer (score 1):

Once you unpack, you should run the install script. For example:

```
$ cd ~/Documents/arduino-1.8.9
$ ./install.sh
```

That should do it. [The Install the Arduino Software (IDE) on Linux](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux) page has more details.

Comment: That works as expected with a shortcut on the desktop, thank you.